# Azure Webapp restarted on 1 node, then startup timeout

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2

We have a lightweight .NET Core API running in an Azure Webapp. In the past we had frequent downtime (3 times a week) out of nowhere, because for some reason the Webapp was restarted on 1 node and it couldn't start up in time: **502.5 ASP.NET Core Process Startup Error.** First of all there should be no reason not to be able to start within 2 minutes, as it just have a few service registrations and that's it. But secondly, why did restart at all?

One time it was because Microsoft was updating their Azure Storage, which Webapps rely on and causes a restart. So I enabled local caching on the Webapp so that updates on the storage don't affect the webapp. And since then everything was stable for months, until today around 13:00.

Same happened; 1 node went down and the API couldn't start anymore. Just this error message **502.5 ASP.NET Core Process Startup Error**. I rebooted the API and it started working again.

I have no idea what to do to prevent this. Does anyone else experience the same issue lately? There is no stacktrace whatsoever, as it looks like it's the runtime that causes the issue and not our code.

Help highly appreciated :)

Regards, Peter